# ReactiveMongo: How to use FindAndModify with JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, bson, reactivemongo

When I update a document in MongoDB, I usually proceed like this:

1. Find the current document and get the version number
2. Increase the version number and save the new document
3. Save the old document in a vermongo collection

Here is my solution – I'm sorry for the amount of code... but it is necessary to let you understand:

```
trait MyDaoComponent {

  private val toObjectId = Writes[String] {
    id => Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> id))
  }

  private val toUpdateObject = (__ \ '$set).json.copyFrom(__.json.pick)

  private def setVersion(version: Option[Int]) = __.json.update(
    version match {
      case Some(v) => (__ \ '_version).json.put(JsNumber(v))
      case None => (__ \ '_version).json.prune
    }
  )

  private def toVersioned(deleted: Boolean) = (__.json.update(
    ( __ \ '_id ).json.copyFrom((__ \ '_id \ '$oid).json.pickBranch) and
    ( __ \ '_id \ '_version).json.copyFrom((__ \ '_version).json.pick) and
    (__ \ '_version).json.update(of[JsValue].map {
      case JsNumber(oldVersion) => if (deleted) JsString(f"deleted:$oldVersion%.0f") else JsNumber(oldVersion)
      case _ => JsNull
    }) and
    (__ \ '_timestamp).json.put(Json.toJson(LocalDateTime.now)) reduce) andThen
    ( __ \ '_id \ '$oid ).json.prune
  )

  ...

  def update(entity: A): Future[Boolean] = {
    entity.id match {
      case Some(id) =>
        val objectId = toObjectId.writes(id)
        collection.find(objectId).cursor[JsValue].headOption.flatMap { _ match {
          case Some(json) =>
            collection.update(
              objectId,
              entity.asJson.transform(
                (__ \ '_id).json.prune andThen 
                setVersion(Some((json as (__ \ '_version).read[Int]) + 1)) andThen
                toUpdateObject
              ).get
            ).flatMap { updateLastError => if (updateLastError.ok) {
              version(json, false).flatMap { versionLastError =>
                if (versionLastError.ok) Future.successful(updateLastError)
                else Future.failed(versionLastError)
              }}
              else Future.failed(updateLastError)
            }
          case None => Future.successful(LastError(true, None, None, None, None, 0, false))
        }}.transform(
          success => if (success.n > 0) true else false,
          failure => failure match { case e: LastError => e.code match { 
            case Some(11001) => DaoServiceException(e.message, Some(DUPLICATE_KEY_ON_UPDATE))
            case _ => DaoServiceException(e.message, Some(DATABASE_ERROR))
          }}
        )
      case None => Future.failed(DaoServiceException("'id' not defined", Some(MISSING_FIELD)))
    } 
  }

  private def version(document: JsValue, deleted: Boolean): Future[LastError] = {
    shadowCollection.insert(document.transform(toVersioned(deleted)).get)
  }
}
```

The code above works... but I'd like to replace the calls to `find` and `update` with an atomic command. I've tried with `FindAndModify`... but it requires `BSONDocuments` while I'm working with pure JSON (the `update` method takes `entity` as an argument, which privide a JSON representation of the data).

Is there a way to convert JSON to BSON so that I can use `FindAndModify`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked at Play-ReactiveMongo and figured out they provide `play.modules.reactivemongo.json.BSONFormats` to convert BSON to/from JSON. I hope that helps.